# No tray and desktop icons afte python upgrade + additional problems

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have deleted old python versions and installed new python (version 3.5.2) and after i restarted computer I have lost system tray and icons on the desktop. I found some solutions that are based on setting up CCSM over terminal but it's not that simple as it looks like. There is no terminal and no ccsm installed anymore so i have followed one tutorial where you need to click on desktop, create new folder and try to run terminal from /usr/bin/ directory. Because there was no terminal i found xterminal and started with entering commands like DISPLAY=:0 ccsm but i got error "bad interpreter".
Anyways, i found some way to delete and reinstall python and i can see its installed in Python-3.5.0 directory. So i was thinking i start the DISPLAY command thru script and run it with python3.5 someScript.py command. That part was success but then i got error " no ccsm " which is true. So...

1.) i try to install with sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
but i got error https://ibb.co/Jdm6BFf

2.) after googling i found some solutions for this but then i land it in the same problem:
https://ibb.co/x8LHFjy

3.) btw. i try to install "minimal" version of python and it was installed but with some errors.

It looks like that path to python is not a problem, because I run the script directly so it must be missing packages, i have no clue how to update it or what to do next...

Purging python and trying to reinstall again ?

Thank you guys for your answers !
E.

Comment: I would try to solve the dependency problems: https://askubuntu.com/a/253115/1060938

Comment: I have try few things and it looks like it stuck on two packages from python2.8 distro. The problem is that i can not uninstall them and i can not make new install.. I manage to load synaptic so it's a bit easier but the problem is still the same. Photo of errors  https://ibb.co/rxxwPjC... i deleted python 3.5 but i can not delete and reinstall python-minimal.